# checking well formed xml and logging the error to file

Tags: xml, bash, sed, find

I have 4,000 xml files in folders a, b, c, and d
Each folder contains 1000 files each. All folders are in main folder called library
I need to check if the xml files are well formed using

> xmllint --noout 100.xml"

command or may be with something better. 
Now incase of error, log the  file name plus folder name in a log file.

> log "library/a/100.xml"

Below is the Pseudo code. I need to build the script to run in shell script or something faster

```
#program check xml format
#!/bin/bash
echo Please, get ready to process
 for i in $(cat "/home/thrinity/library/);
  do
    xmllint --noout "$i" ;
    if error
      #log filefolder & file name
      print error to errorlog.txt
    else
end do
```

I am looking for error where a tag is missing.. something like.. 038339 here the invoice closing tag is missing or any way I can capture this

For those who might be intrested. The code below worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04 machine

> find /YourMainFolder -name '*.xml' -print | xargs -I "{}" sh -c 'File="{}";xmllint --noout "${File}" || readlink -f {} >> errorlog.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /YourMainFolder -name '*.xml' -print | xargs -I "%ARG%" sh -c 'File="%ARG%";xmllint --noout "${File}" || echo "Error in ${File}" > errorlog.txt'
```

will depend of your error, here it is based on a Return code <> 0

using missing tag

```
find /YourMainFolder -name '*.xml' -print | xargs -I "%ARG%" sh -c 'File="%ARG%";grep -q -E "<invoice>.*</invoice>" || echo "Error in ${File}" > errorlog.txt'
```

Comment: adapt your request in original post for this, i change my reply

Comment: I tried the first script it is giving error xargs: {} No such file or directory. Any reason why.. P.s I am not looking specifically for invoice tag error.. but the errro I am looking for is when a closing tag is missing..

Comment: i change and use `%ARG%` instead of `{}` on my sytem and surround it with double quote after `-i`, works fine, on my linux and aix

Comment: I tried but still getting the error code... However the command find /YourMainFolder -name '*.xml' -print | xargs -i returns my file

Comment: The problem lies here "This option is a synonym for -Ireplace-str if replace-str is specified, and for -I{} otherwise. This option is deprecated; use -I instead." I ried I and it worked.. i is deprecated

Comment: sorry, thjs is indead `-I` on my system an human error when copied the code